# Query not returning any results for time difference of 1 minute?

Tags: java, date, jpa, querydsl

My code looks like

**Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal amount;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean debit;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime date;
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Member member;
```

**Query**

```
    @Nonnull
    public List<Transaction> getTransactionsForUserMonthAndYear(@Nonnull final Member existingMember, final int month,
                                                                final int year) {
        final LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        final LocalDateTime endDate = startDate.plusMonths(1);

        return crudService.query(transaction)
                .where(transaction.member.eq(existingMember))
                .where(transaction.date.goe(startDate))
                .where(transaction.date.lt(endDate))
                .list(transaction);
    }
```

and my test looks like

```
 @Test
    public void testGetTransactionsDifferentMonths() {
        final Member member = new Member("newUser@gmail.com", "userExternalId", "clientId", "clientSecret");
        final Category category = new Category("Groceries", "Food & Drink");
        crudService.create(member);
        crudService.create(category);
        jpaRule.changeTransaction();

        final LocalDateTime startOfMonth = LocalDateTime.of(2014, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        final LocalDateTime nextMonth = startOfMonth.plusMonths(1).plusMinutes(1);
        final Transaction sprouts = new Transaction("Sprouts", new BigDecimal("12345.346"), true, startOfMonth, member, category);
        final Transaction costco = new Transaction("Costco", new BigDecimal("100.295"), true, nextMonth, member, category);

        crudService.create(sprouts);
        crudService.create(costco);
        jpaRule.changeTransaction();

        {
            final List<Transaction> transactions = new TransactionQueries(crudService).getTransactionsForUserMonthAndYear(member, 1, 2014);
            assertFalse(transactions.isEmpty());
            assertEquals(1, transactions.size());
            assertEquals(sprouts, transactions.get(0));
        }
        {
            final List<Transaction> transactions = new TransactionQueries(crudService).getTransactionsForUserMonthAndYear(member, 2, 2014);
            assertFalse(transactions.isEmpty());
            assertEquals(1, transactions.size());
            assertEquals(costco, transactions.get(0));
        }
    }
```

**What I expect?**
I expect that

```
final List<Transaction> transactions = new TransactionQueries(crudService).getTransactionsForUserMonthAndYear(member, 2, 2014);
```

should return `costco` transaction, but the result is empty.

I am not sure what is wrong with this query

**UPDATE**

I tried certain things

- If I do

> final LocalDateTime nextMonth =
>   startOfMonth.plusMonths(1).plusMinutes(1);

The query fails at

```
final List<Transaction> transactions = new TransactionQueries(crudService).getTransactionsForUserMonthAndYear(member, 2, 2014);
            assertFalse(transactions.isEmpty());
```

meaning no transactions found for `February`

- If I do

> ```
> final LocalDateTime nextMonth = startOfMonth.plusMonths(1).plusHours(1);
> ```

It fails at

```
 final List<Transaction> transactions = new TransactionQueries(crudService).getTransactionsForUserMonthAndYear(member, 1, 2014);
            assertFalse(transactions.isEmpty());
            assertEquals(1, transactions.size());
```

with error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :2
```

- and If I do

> ```
> final LocalDateTime nextMonth = startOfMonth.plusMonths(1).plusDays(1);
> ```

All test pass!

This totally blew my mind, I do not know how things are working here

Comment: `crudService.create(costco);`?

Comment: actually `assertEquals(sprouts, transactions.get(0));` is fine, so that I believe is not an issue

Comment: So it works when you don't add the extra minute?

Comment: Could your crudService somehow mess things up? Can you debug what dates actually make it into JPA?

Comment: Wild guess, might it be related to Timezones, somehow. Can you add @Temporal(TIMESTAMP) timestamp. By code it seems it should not, but maybe there is some configuration in JPA layer or something.

Comment: using which JPA implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried these advices https://weblogs.java.net/blog/montanajava/archive/2014/06/17/using-java-8-datetime-classes-jpa ?
Namely, write & register a jpa custom converter to map between the new date api and the java.sql classes.

Comment: Thanks @dna, I was using Converter but seems like `autoApply=true` is not working as expected. I changed it to `@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime date;` and things are behaving as expected even with `        final LocalDateTime nextMonth = startOfMonth.plusMonths(1).plusNanos(1);`. Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

I think adding @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) should solve this.

*Based on exception, that you received while trying Temporal*

There is an article, regarding using Java8 with JPA

https://weblogs.java.net/blog/montanajava/archive/2014/06/17/using-java-8-datetime-classes-jpa

*Based on the article.*

You need to create AttributeConverter

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter implements AttributeConverter {
    @Override
    public java.sql.Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime entityValue) {
        return Timestamp.valueOf(entityValue);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(java.sql.Timestamp databaseValue) {
        return databaseValue.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

Here is a sample project

https://bitbucket.org/montanajava/jpaattributeconverters

Comment: `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property:` when I do `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private LocalDateTime date;`
`